# Submitting scores to Google Play Games leaderboards and displaying new rank(s)

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-games

***I'm working on a game where scores are submitted to leaderboards in an activity and the new high scores are displayed with ranks in a fragment. I have something (somewhat) functional, but the success rate is ~10%.***

The flow is as follows:

**Method handleLeaders**

This method gets the current scores for each leaderboard, and if the new score is better, it is submitted and a new newHigh object is created with the score and added to an ArrayList. After all 3 of the leaderboards are handled, the method setHighs is called. (Errors are checked for in each of the leaderboard calls)

```
public void handleLeaders(boolean win, int size, double t, final int toupees) {
    if(win) {
        final long time = (long) t;
        // Toupees
        Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient,
                getString(R.string.leaderboard_trumps_toupeed),
                LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                        LeaderboardScore c = arg0.getScore();
                        int old;
                        if (c != null)
                            old = (int) c.getRawScore();
                        else
                            old = 0;
                        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_trumps_toupeed), old + toupees);

                        GameEndOverlay.newHighs.add(new newHigh("Trumps Toupee'd", old + toupees));

                        Status status = arg0.getStatus();
                        int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();

                        if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA)
                            GameEndOverlay.highsError = true;


                        if(++GameEndOverlay.leaderboardsCompleted == 3)
                            ((GameEndOverlay) gameEndOverlayFrag).setHighs();

                    }
                });

        if (size == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.size_apprentice)) {

            // Wins
            Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient,
                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_apprentice_wins),
                    LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                    LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                            LeaderboardScore c = arg0.getScore();
                            int wins;
                            if (c != null)
                                wins = (int) c.getRawScore();
                            else
                                wins = 0;
                            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_apprentice_wins), wins + 1);

                            GameEndOverlay.newHighs.add(new newHigh("Apprentice Wins", wins + 1));

                            Status status = arg0.getStatus();
                            int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();

                            if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA)
                                GameEndOverlay.highsError = true;


                            if(++GameEndOverlay.leaderboardsCompleted == 3)
                                ((GameEndOverlay) gameEndOverlayFrag).setHighs();
                        }
                    });

            // Speed
            Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient,
                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_fastest_apprentice),
                    LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                    LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                            LeaderboardScore c = arg0.getScore();
                            long old_time;
                            if(c != null) {
                                old_time = c.getRawScore();
                                Log.d("time", old_time + "");
                                if(time < old_time) {
                                    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_fastest_apprentice), time);
                                    GameEndOverlay.newHighs.add(new newHigh("Fastest Apprentice", time));
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_fastest_apprentice), time);
                                GameEndOverlay.newHighs.add(new newHigh("Fastest Apprentice", time));
                            }

                            Status status = arg0.getStatus();
                            int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();

                            if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA) 
                                GameEndOverlay.highsError = true;


                            if(++GameEndOverlay.leaderboardsCompleted == 3)
                                ((GameEndOverlay) gameEndOverlayFrag).setHighs();

                        }
                    });
        }
}
```

**Method setHighs**

This method gets the ranks of each corresponding newHigh and stores the new rank inside the object. After all ranks are gathered, the method setSecondHighs is called. (Errors are checked for in each of the leaderboard calls)

```
public void setHighs() {
    if(getActivity() == null)
        return;

    ranksComputed = 0;

    for(newHigh highRaw : newHighs) {
        final newHigh high = highRaw;
        switch(high.getName()) {
            case "Trumps Toupee'd":
                Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient,
                        getString(R.string.leaderboard_trumps_toupeed),
                        LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                        LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                                if(arg0.getScore() == null) {
                                    highsError = true;
                                    ranksComputed++;
                                    if(ranksComputed >= newHighs.size())
                                        setSecondHighs();
                                    return;
                                }
                                high.setRank(arg0.getScore().getRank());

                                Status status = arg0.getStatus();
                                int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();

                                if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA)
                                    GameEndOverlay.highsError = true;

                                ranksComputed++;
                                if(ranksComputed >= newHighs.size())
                                    setSecondHighs();
                            }
                        });
                break;
            case "Apprentice Wins":
                Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient,
                        getString(R.string.leaderboard_apprentice_wins),
                        LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                        LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                                if(arg0.getScore() == null) {
                                    highsError = true;
                                    ranksComputed++;
                                    if(ranksComputed >= newHighs.size())
                                        setSecondHighs();
                                    return;
                                }
                                high.setRank(arg0.getScore().getRank());

                                Status status = arg0.getStatus();
                                int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();

                                if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA)
                                    GameEndOverlay.highsError = true;

                                ranksComputed++;
                                if(ranksComputed >= newHighs.size())
                                    setSecondHighs();
                            }
                        });
                break;
            case "Fastest Apprentice":
                Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient,
                        getString(R.string.leaderboard_fastest_apprentice),
                        LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                        LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                                if(arg0.getScore() == null) {
                                    highsError = true;
                                    ranksComputed++;
                                    if(ranksComputed >= newHighs.size())
                                        setSecondHighs();
                                    return;
                                }
                                high.setRank(arg0.getScore().getRank());

                                Status status = arg0.getStatus();
                                int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();

                                if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA)
                                    GameEndOverlay.highsError = true;

                                ranksComputed++;
                                if(ranksComputed >= newHighs.size())
                                    setSecondHighs();
                            }
                        });
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

**Method setSecondHighs**

This method either displays an error or new ranks+score to the user

```
public void setSecondHighs() {
  if(highsError)
    // display an error to the user
  else
    // display ranks+score to user
}
```

The issue is that there are a LOT of API calls here, and the submissions are hanging at different points in the calls. I know there has to be a better way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: It seems like you are implementing a lot more low level stuff than I usually do when working with leaderboards.  submitScore() is fire and forget according to the docs.  If you have an issue with using this form of the API, take a look at submitScoreImmediate().  I've noticed that under the hood, using submitScore(), the GoogleApiClient sometimes caches the submissions and submits them as Scores.submitMultiple().

Comment: the success rate is ~10% <- do you mean that can you post your log.d and say a little more about how what you are expecting compares to what results you observe?

Comment: After more debugging, many of the onResult calls return a null LoadPlayerScoreResult object no matter of my Internet connection. It's not an every time either. Sometimes it's null, sometime it's not. This problem usually occurs in the setHighs method, but occasionally happens the handleLeaders method

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when trying to increment leaderboard scores, Google has put a limit on the number of requests you can make in an undocumented/unconfirmed time period. Usually 3 consecutive requests to retrieve leaderboard data will go through and the rest will return network related errors. More details for other users facing the same issue can be viewed here: [Android - Google play service : Leaderboard, limited number of requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995922/android-google-play-service-leaderboard-limited-number-of-requests)