# Android loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore not always returning result values

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

`loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore` method sometimes returns the value from my leaderboards and other times there is no result, so 999 is returned for `LB_SCORE` and `LB_RANK`. I am connected to google play games service, I am able to view the leaderboards using the `startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mClient, leaderboardId), 1);` so I can confirm there are valid scores. How can I make calling `loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore` more reliable and consistent?

```
public void populateLeaderboards(){

    String[] leaderboardIdArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.leaderboard_id_array);
    String[] leaderboardNameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.leaderboard_name_array);

    leaderboardList = new ArrayList<LeaderboardItem>();
    leaderboardList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < leaderboardIdArray.length; i++) {

        Log.d("leaderboardIdArray", leaderboardIdArray[i]);

         getLeaderboardData(leaderboardIdArray[i],leaderboardNameArray[i]);
LeaderboardItem(leaderboardIdArray[i], LB_NAME, String.valueOf(LB_SCORE), String.valueOf(LB_RANK));


    }

}     

private void getLeaderboardData(final String leaderboardId,final String  leaderboardName) {

    Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mClient, leaderboardId, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {
    //Games.Leaderboards.loadPlayerCenteredScores(mClient, leaderboardId, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 1, true).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(final Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult scoreResult) {

            if (isScoreResultValid(scoreResult)) {
                // here you can get the score like this

                LB_SCORE = scoreResult.getScore().getRawScore();
                LB_RANK = scoreResult.getScore().getRank();


            } else {

                LB_SCORE = 999;
                LB_RANK = 999;

            }

            LeaderboardItem leaderboardItem = new LeaderboardItem(leaderboardId, leaderboardName, String.valueOf(LB_SCORE), String.valueOf(LB_RANK));
            leaderboardList.add(leaderboardItem);


        }


    });
}


private boolean isScoreResultValid(final Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult scoreResult) {
    return scoreResult != null && GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK == scoreResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() && scoreResult.getScore() != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar issues, and I see that [other post confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995922/android-google-play-service-leaderboard-limited-number-of-requests) my suspicions that making too many calls will result in network error. So my suggestions is that you are abusing play service too much.

Comment: Do you know if there is any official Google documentation on this? Thanks.