# load-CurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore is always failure

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

i wanna get users get last score in playstore but i research 2 days and i got nothing. Finally, i wrote the code (i'm not sure it'll be wrong code) but always get failure.

write load-CurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore delete the "-" for fk17bH1SYLoBdGsBaDedPR2EE3JUt8oRS7qd

this is the code;

```
                Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(
                "CgkIiMyT6f0SEAIQHg", LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore> leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData) {
                        if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData != null) {
                            long score = 0;
                            if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get() != null) {
                                score = leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get().getRawScore();

                                Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, Long.toString(score), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "null 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "null 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "addOnFailureListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from these links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026704/android-loadcurrentplayerleaderboardscore-not-always-returning-result-values) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995922/android-google-play-service-leaderboard-limited-number-of-requests), making too many calls might result this kind of error. Suggested action is avoid abusing play service too much. Also, you can try spreading out your requests instead of making them all at one time.

Comment: thanks for answer. i'll accept the answer. i decide to not use the google play service :)