# LoadPlayerScoreResult.getScore() returns null while its not

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have google play services included in my app, and everything is working fine except getting the score from the current player for a selected leaderboard.

I have 5 leaderboards, and i have made a method which takes `LEADERBOARD_ID` , `SavedTopScoreInSharedPreferences` , `SharedPreferences_KEY` as params.

For example:

1. First leaderboard.
2. Second leaderboard.
3. Third leaderboard.

When the user sign in, i check if there's a saved score in the leaderboard, if yes take it and save it in the sharedpreferences, the problem is, there is a score and the leaderboard shows it, but it returns null, for example the first three leaderboards.

My code :

```
 private void CheckScore(final String mID, final int mTopScore, final String mKey){
        if(isSignedIn()){
            Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient,mID,
                    LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                    LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult( Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                    if(isScoreResultValid(arg0)){
                        long score = arg0.getScore().getRawScore();
                        if(mTopScore > score){
                            Log.i("GsadasdSc","Local Score is bigger: " + mTopScore + " - Score: " + score);
                            Log.i("GsadasdSc","ID: " + mKey + "\n" + "-----------------" + "\n");
                            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, mID, mTopScore);
                        } else {
                            editor.putInt(mKey, (int) score).apply();
                            Log.i("GsadasdSc","Local Score is smaller: " + mTopScore + " - Score: " + score);
                            Log.i("GsadasdSc","ID: " + mKey + "\n" + "-----------------" + "\n");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, mID, mTopScore);
                        Log.i("GsadasdSc","NULL ID: " + mKey + "\n" + "-----------------" + "\n");
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }

    private boolean isScoreResultValid(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult         scoreResult) {
return scoreResult != null && GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK == scoreResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() && scoreResult.getScore() != null;
    }
```

This code is implemented in the overrided `onConnected` method.

Output :

```
Local Score is smaller: 0 - Score: 30
ID: Sham
NULL ID: Hama
NULL ID: Homs
```

Comment: I'm using the same code, it returns null when i check for various leaderboards, but it returns with a result when i check for only one leaderboard.

Comment: When isScoreResultValid() returns false, what is the value of arg0.getStatus().getStatusCode()?

Comment: First try, it was 0, then it's 4.

Comment: Taking from the page, the 0 belongs to the first 3 methods calling, while the 4 is for the others called methods, link : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes.

Comment: After knowing that i can get the error code, I've googled and seems i can only request 3 times every 25 seconds, link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995922/android-google-play-service-leaderboard-limited-number-of-requests .

Comment: What's the content of `isScoreResultValid`?

Comment: I've updated the code.